# I want to restore the database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am to take the backup of database, but i m not able to restore the same backup file. Here is the backup code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

class Backupsql extends JDialog {

    public boolean backupDB(String dbUser, String dbPass, String dbName) {
        String sourcePath = null;
        boolean result = false;
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int i = fc.showSaveDialog(Backupsql.this);
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        sourcePath = file.getPath();
        String filename = file.getName();
        sourcePath = sourcePath + ".sql";

        String executeCmd =
            "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\mysqldump -u "
            + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r " + sourcePath;

        Process runtimeProcess;
        try {
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
            if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
                compressFile(sourcePath);
                result = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("error" + e);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void compressFile(String srcFile) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            String destPath = srcFile.replace(".sql", ".zip");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(srcFile);
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);

            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the restore command i m using.

```
String[] executeCmd = new String[]{
    "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysql.exe", "--user="
    + user, "--password=" + password, "-e", " source " + Unzippath};
```

Is my code correct? Can I get some suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able"? What errors do you get? Can you restore the backup manually (i.e. not using a Java application)?

Comment: Yes i m able to restore the backup manually

Comment: means i have done a java Backup code as well as java restore code but both the code dont work for the same file. i m unable to restore the java backup file through java restore code

Comment: Ok, so what error message/problem to you face when doing it with your application?

Comment: database restored unsuccessfully i guess u must be knowing that MySQL has two inbuilt functions Backup and Restore .The same i want to implement in my project

Comment: `Yes i m able to restore the backup manually` - means, your backup method shown above works well. You should show us the restore method instead (not only the command string you are using, but how is it called) (and, please, format it so that it is readable)

Comment: Also consider `ProcessBuilder` over `Runtime.exec()`.

Answer (score 1):

Look into MySQL [Backup/Restore](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/backup-types.html). The following SQL can simply be executed with JDBC, and is more general. It *is* also intended for handling *full* backups.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '...'
```